# Does the Sleep and Charge feature of USB 3.0 in Samsung 5 Laptop work with Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, usb, sleep

I am using samsung series 5 np550pc s03in which comes with windows 8 preinstalled. I would like to dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu 12.10.

I have had searched many websites but there is no information whether dual boot with ubuntu 12.10 breaks USB (USB 3.0) sleep and charge feature. Windows 8 Supports USB Sleep and Charge as a default and i use this feature for charging my mobile device while traveling.

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: The best way to figure this out is to create a Live USB/DVD and boot from it and choose the option "Try Ubuntu without Installing". Then you can try to make it sleep and see if this feature works.

Comment: Thats good idea, but i am not sure whether it can simulate the dual boot environment which i need to work with. i.e., i mean Even if USB/DVD Boot without installation supports USB Sleep and Charge, its not same that Dual Boot supports that. Anyhow thanks for tip!

Comment: I think the only problem may be, the computer may not sleep when booted from Live DVD/USB. If you can figure this out, please post an answer below and mark it as correct. This will help others.

Comment: I have finally installed Ubuntu 12.10 And Sleep and Charge feature works well and Good as it is a BIOS Feature rather than OS Feature.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer (and remove the '[solved]' from the title). That's how these sites work. (It's fine to answer your own question, you can even accept it after a certain amount of time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally tried to boot ubuntu 12.10 alongside windows 8. Sleep and Charge is BIOS Feature Hence Irrespective of the OS Installed, it would work Fine. Confirmed working fine on Samsung Series 5 NP550PC S03IN.